# google cast sender app does not disconnect on first try

Tags: java, android, google-cast, chromecast

I integrated google cast support into my android application. I am able to connect and play video remotely with no problems. The only issue I seem to be running into **intermittently** is that sometimes in order to disconnect from the cast device I need to  disconnect then connect then disconnect again.

Any ideas as to why this behaviour is happening?

I am using the Cast Companion Library which uses the following logic to disconnect:

```
protected GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
.....
......
     if (null != mApiClient && mApiClient.isConnected()) {
         LOGD(TAG, "Trying to disconnect");
         mApiClient.disconnect();
         if (null != mMediaRouter) {
            mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute());
         }
     }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be needing to do that, what is your disconnect logic?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I am using the CCL , it handles the disconnect logic. Unless I am incorrect. Also note that this happens intermittently.

Comment: @AliNaddaf  CCL: Cast companion library

Comment: Please try CastVideos-android project; that uses the CCL library as well and see if that works fine or not. That way we can narrow down the issue to CCL or your sender application.